# How does Connection.Execute work in VBScript?

Tags: javascript, sql, vbscript, recordset

How does `Connection.Execute` work in VBScript?

```vb
Dim Connection
Set Connection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
connection.open(Parameter)

Dim sql
sql = "sql query"

Dim RowsReturn
Err.Clear
Connection.CommandTimeout = 30  
Connection.Execute SQLStatement, RowsReturn, 1
```

I am trying to rewrite the code in JavaScript. What am I missing below?

```javascript
var connection = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");
var rs = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");  
connectionstring = "Connection String "
connection.Open(connectionstring);

var sql = "Sql query"

rs = connection.execute(sql);
```

I need help with understanding for the statement `Connection.Execute SQLStatement, RowsReturn, 1`.

Comment: When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675023.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Syntax for row-returning:

```
Set objrs=objconn.Execute(commandtext,ra,options)
```

Syntax for non-row-returning:

```
objconn.Execute commandtext,ra,options
```

**commandtext:** Required. The SQL statement, stored procedure, or provider-specific text to execute

**ra:** Optional. The number of records affected by the query

**options:** Optional. Sets how the provider should evaluate the commandtext parameter

In your case:

1. commandText = SQLStatement
2. ra = RowsReturn
3. options = adCmdText = 1

See [ADO Execute Method documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/met_conn_execute.asp)
and [options documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/met_conn_execute.asp#commandtypeenum)

I hope it helps you. Bye.